# PHP MYSQL Condition WHERE Count()

Tags: php, mysql

This is the query I'm using

```
SELECT b.event_id FROM bookings b

LEFT JOIN usermeta um ON b.person_id = um.user_id
WHERE um.meta_value= '1' AND um.meta_key = 'Value'

GROUP BY b.event_id
```

It displays Events where users who booked those events satisfy the condition 'Value=1'. Good.

I need to change this query and display Events where more than 1 user satisfying that same condition have a booking.

In other words, display Events booked by more than 1 user having Value=1.

Could you please help me getting there. Thanks a lot

Comment: Remove the group by clause. So far it groups all the events (uncaring of the people who booked it) which has the same id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT b.event_id, b.person_id FROM bookings b

LEFT JOIN usermeta um ON b.person_id = um.user_id
WHERE um.meta_value= '1' AND um.meta_key = 'Value'

GROUP BY b.event_id 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT b.person_id) > 1
```